# Show the derived set is closed using the fact that the ball around an accumulation point contains infinitely many points of the set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been working on this for several days and feel stuck (along with my peers). Our professor has hinted that we should use the fact that:

$$
x \in A' \iff \forall \delta > 0 (B(x;\delta) \bigcap A \text{ is infinite })
$$

and perhaps the converse. Hints appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we are working in metric spaces and we know (presumably) that $x \in A'$ iff for every $\delta > 0$, we know that $B(x,\delta) \cap A$ is infinite.

To see that $A'$ is closed, we pick $x \notin A'$ and we need to find an open ball around $x$ that is disjoint from $A'$. This will show that $x$ is an interior point of $X \setminus A'$, and as $x$ is arbitrary, $X \setminus A'$ is open, so $A'$ is closed.

Well, using the fact, $ x \notin A'$ implies that there exists some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap A$ is finite.

Now let $y \in B(x,r)$. Then as open balls are open, find some $r' > 0$ such that $B(y,r') \subseteq B(x,r)$. So $B(y,r') \cap A \subseteq B(x,r) \cap A$ which is finite. So $y \notin A'$ by the same fact. As $y$ is arbitrary, $B(x,r)$ is disjoint from $A'$, as required. So $A'$ is closed.

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly we have put an open ball around $x$ which is in the compliment because it is disjoint. Since this compliment is open (as we can put balls around all the points) we know that the derived set is closed.

Comment: @Chris, yes, this is the reasoning behind it. Added it to the body for clarity.

Comment: The edit is a helpful clarification thank you! This is very well explained.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.